# HTML object tag not inheriting CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, object

I am hosting my personal website on Github Pages, and since this allows no server-side scripting I've replaced all my `php include` statements with `object` tags. The (very unfinished) site is live [here](http://benplumley.github.io/) and as you can see, the navbar along the top does not inherit any styles from the page that contains it.

How can I fix this? The styles that affect the navbar are defined in bootstrap.css and custom.css, both of which are linked to in the head of the parent page. The HTML document that contains the navbar does not contain head or body tags because they would be nested inside the body tags of the parent page. Putting a head section into the navbar's source would mean all my CSS and JS loads three times per page load (parent, navbar, footer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pages loaded with `<object>` are, essentially, the same as pages loaded with `<iframe>`. They are *separate* documents and styles will not cascade into them.

> How can I fix this?

Include your styles in each page.

As a horrible hack, you could use JavaScript to dynamically add the scripts and links to the pages in the frames … but you'd be better off doing it up front.

> The HTML document that contains the navbar does not contain head or body tags because they would be nested inside the body tags of the parent page.

It is a separate HTML document. By not including the head section you are making it invalid.

> Putting a head section into the navbar's source would mean all my CSS and JS loads three times per page load (parent, navbar, footer).

No, it wouldn't. Browsers cache files they have loaded before.

---

As an aside, if I was stuck with a host that didn't allow server side scripting, I'd use a template preprocessor (such as `ttree` or wintersmith.io) rather then any kind of client side include (like frames).

Comment: I think I'm going to go with preprocessing, since I've tried putting it in with its own head section and stylesheets and the result was horrible.

Comment: why is using JS to load an HTML template a "horrible hack"? isn't that the same as jquery, angular, etc. do in their HTML loading functions?

Answer (score 1):

My  tagged linked file is included in a 300x150px frame. I can't seem to be able to change that, even if I did add an "object" line in my css file specifying height and width.

I tried 100%, 100vh/vw, auto, even fixed sizes in px, nothing changes, I still get a 300x150px object and the text of my .html file in it.

Here is the code of the main html file (it's inside my body tag, I have quite long headers and footers):

```html
<! GGC 3-2 : main>
            <object type="text/html" target="_parent" data="./sections/main.html#maintxt"> 
                Your browser doesn’t support the object tag. 
            </object>
```

here is the code of the file I'd like to become the "main" block :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>              
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=unicode">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.9">
    <link href="/css/stylem.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css"></style>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="main">
        <p class="main" id="maintxt">My Text</p>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

and finally the css I made for the object tag :

```css
object {
    height:100vh;
    width:100vh;
    display:block;
}

#maintxt {
    color: #000;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    line-height: 0.95;
    direction: rtl;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12em;

    position: absolute;
    left: 15vw; 
}

.main {width:auto;height:auto;}
```

Thanks for any answer.